# Identify Resource Usage of a Process: CPU, Memory and I/O

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, command-line

1. I need to request some AWS resources and in order to do so, I need to identify what are my requirements for:

   - Number of CPU cores (maybe GPUs as well) (performs parallel processing)
   - Amount of Memory required
   - I/O & network read/write time (optional / good to know)

How can I profile my script so that I know if I am using the requested resources to the fullest?

2. How can I profile the whole system? Something along the following lines:

   i. Request large number of compute resources (CPUs and RAM) on AWS

   ii. Start the system profiler

   iii. Run my program and wait for it to finish

   iv. Stop the system profiler and ***identify the peak #CPUs and RAM used***

Context: Unix / Linux

Comment: Without any [MCVE] your question is not a programming question but a sysadmin one (so should better be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ...) or it is too broad. I recommend showing in your question a simplified version of the script

Answer (score 0):

You could use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), but there are two variants of it.

- the `time` builtin in most shells is usually not enough for your needs, so...
- you need the `/usr/bin/time` program from the `time` package

Then you'll run `/usr/bin/time -v yourscript`

and inside your script you could use the [`times` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52318/50557))

You also should consider using [perf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) and [oprofile(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/oprofile.1.html)

At last, you might eventually code something or use something querying the kernel thru `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)). Utilities like `xosview` are using that.

Comment: Will it also get me stats for any child processes that my program might spawn? Even cumulative  stat of all the child processes as one is fine